# Bootstrap 4 removing / hiding a class

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kus28.png)

Is it possible to remove a class on bootstrap 4 in medium viewport without using javascript / jquery? For example this code above i wanted to remove the border-right class on medium viewport. Is there a class like on Tailwind css "md:border-right".

P.S. Sorry for my bad english it is not my native language.

Comment: Instead of removing the border right class, use CSS specificity and combinators to catch both classes together and reverse whatever is done in border-right. For example `.col-md-4.border-right { .... }`. Hope that helps?

Comment: @GurtejSingh Thanks that worked perfectly didn't know i could combine 2 classes

Comment: @GurtejSingh oops it worked but i also removed the border on lg viewport

Answer (score 0):

You can use a media query and override that class for medium viewports, add a class to the div with the name, for example, .no-border, and then you can do something like this

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px){
    .no-boder{
        border: none;
    }
}
```

Let me know if that help!

Comment: So i have to override the bootstrap CSS? I'm currently using the Bootstrap CSS CDN.

Comment: Yes, you will need to do that in order to achieve what you want, if you use .border-right, all the elements in the page with that class will be affected, you only want to delete the borders for one element on medium viewports, so you need a media query media query for medium devices, and you need to add a new class.